# Display first index number of array for particular value

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

`sy` is a 1x501 array, simulating vertical displacement in projectile motion.
I wish to display the index number of the first value to fall below -4.

An example would be:

```
sy = [0.1  0.3  0.7  1.0  0.7   0.2  -1.0  -3.2  -4.1  -5.3  -6.0];
```

I need a method to display the index number 9, as -4.1 is the first value to fall below -4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare each element of `sy` to `-4` to find which ones are below -4: `sy < -4`. This returns a logical (Boolean) array of the same size as `sy`. Next, use [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to return the index of the first element that is true:

```
find(sy < -4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = sy(t)
threshold = -4
idx = 0
for i = 1:length(data)
    if data(i) < threshold
        idx = i
        break
    end
end
if idx = 0
    display("Condition not met!")
else
    display("First instance found at index " + idx)
end
```

Or, even better, use `find`.

```
data = sy(t)
threshold = -4
idx = find(data < threshold,1)
if length(idx) = 0
    display("Condition not met!")
else
    display("First instance found at index " + idx)
end
```